# difference between task and function that return task

Tags: c#

hi i know we can run task with c# like this

```
Task t1 = new Task(new Action(A))
```

but A is static function
can we have non static function and when we have function that return task
can we have run like

```
new Task(new Action(A));
```

if we cant what is def between

```
  static void A()
 {
        Console.Write("task");
 }
    Task t1 = new Task(new Action(A));
```

and

```
  public async Task<BitmapImage> Set_Image(string location_in_server, string location_to_save, string name_file)
        {
            Ntaban.Api.API_HttpClient apic = new Ntaban.Api.API_HttpClient();
        string location = location_to_save + name_file;
        string location_directory = location_to_save;
        if (Directory.Exists(location_directory) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(location_directory);
        }
        if (File.Exists(location) == false)
        {
            await apic.download_file_async(location_in_server + name_file, location, null);
        }
        BitmapImage s1 = new BitmapImage();
        s1.BeginInit();
        s1.UriSource = new System.Uri(location_to_save + name_file);
        s1.EndInit();
        return s1;
    }
  imgProfile.Source = savefile.Set_Image(Ntaban.Api.API_server.Host + "/content/profile/", St_Major.Directories.Directory_Main, lst.First().picAdr).Result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i know we can run task with c# like this

That doesn't actually run the task. It creates a task that is ready to run but not actually scheduled yet.

Oh, and you shouldn't *ever* do this. There is literally no reason to *ever* use the `Task` constructor.

> what is def between

The task constructor creates a task that is not running. Presumably, code not shown would schedule the task on the thread pool (e.g., `t1.Start(TaskScheduler.Default)`), and in that case it would execute `A` on a thread pool thread.

The task returned by an `async` method represents the execution of that method. Note that `async` implies an asynchronous task - this is *not* executed on a thread pool thread. I have a blog post that goes into more detail on [how `async` and `await` work](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: i khow about this but when we have function that return task<string>(for example) is it run as task . 
in the other words I like to run my function in task or thread or other core of cpu what should we do؟؟؟

Comment: @amirjahany: If you want to run code on a thread pool, then use `Task.Run`.

Comment: thanks to your answer . can you tell me about threadpool i cant understand it

Comment: @amirjahany: No, but you can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.110).aspx).